# how to fix Error:No such property: javaOuptuts for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl

Tags: android, junit5

hi I'm new in Kotlin and i want to do unit test.
So i add this configuration that i get from this link : 
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/junit-5-getting-started/

here is what i have added:
in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    /** Add junit5 plugin as a buildscript dependency**/
    classpath 'de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.0.0-M2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

and this is my app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

/**  Run the junit's plugin as part of the build**/
apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tharwa.solid.tharwa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

/**
Add a configuration for junit 5
 **/
junitPlatform {
    jupiterVersion '5.0.0-M3'
    platformVersion '1.0.0-M3'
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'

    // retrofit
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
    //RxAndroid
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"

    // rxandroid
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"

    //Gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    // test dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' //A configuration for junit 5
    testCompile junitJupiter()
    testProvided "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0-M3"

    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
    testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0-rc1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

once i synchronise the project with Gradle Files i always got this error:

```
Error:No such property: javaOuptuts for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl

Gradle sync failed: No such property: javaOuptuts for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (11s 191ms)
```

**I have android 3.0.1 as a version**.
I have searched and tryed several thing but it does not work for me.
Can some one help please.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

it happend to me while i was upgrading my gradle in studio there was an error. i went inside the project settings it was using that build it had failed to upgrade to. i downgraded it back to the one i was using before the upgrade and it started working agian.